# IOS Swift Parse Password Reset Page applying Rules

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, passwords, verification

I have an application using Parse to store server side data. I apply rules to the entry of a password using a regex successfully. However when I use Parse's PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground function the user is emailed a password reset URL which allows any password to be entered in the reset. The problem is that when the user returns to log into the application with their new password it may not conform to the rules set in the regex. How can I enforce password rules in Parse?

Comment: "IOS Swift Parse Password Reset Page applying Rules": what does that mean?? Please avoid stuffing keywords in the question title, use an actual question in English. The last sentence of your post is a good candidate for a title: "How can I enforce password rules in Parse?". You should also change your "parsing" tag to something relevant like "parse.com".